# What happens if default-src not defined in CSP

Tags: content-security-policy

We have set of CSP derivatives that allow only mentioned domains, We didn't mentioned all the derivatives.

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'  *.youtube.com; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src cdn.swaychat.com *.facebook.com  www.youtube.com;
```

My question is, what happens to other not defined derivatives like img-src, media-src. For a image, it will look for img-src, since its not defined it will look for the fallback default-src, since i also not defined default-src. What happens then.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question! I'd assume that everything else will be allowed.

Comment: What happens is that document is allowed to load any resources of that relevant resource type without any restrictions. For example, if the policy for a document doesn’t specify an `img-src` directive and also doesn’t specify any `default-src` directive, then the document is allowed to load any images, without any restrictions.

Comment: One way to think about this is that CSP directives only ever define restrictions — that is, the presence of a particular CSP directive can only further restrict what resources a document is allowed to load. Therefore, if a policy defines no directives for a particular type of resource, then there are no restrictions on the document loading resources of that type. So if a policy has no `img-src` directive and not `default-src` directive, then that policy defines no restrictions on what images the document is allowed to load, and therefore it can load any images from anywhere.

Comment: Yet another way to think about it: A document without any CSP policy at all is allowed to load any resources without any restrictions. So serving a CSP policy with the document can only have the effect of adding restrictions on what resources the document can load — a policy will never have the effect of relaxing any restrictions to allow anything that otherwise wasn’t already allowed. So if a policy doesn’t explicitly define any restrictions at all for a particular type of resource, then all resources of that type are allowed — just at the normally would be if there were no CSP policy at all.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thanks for your clear explanation. Its very helpful and resolves my doubts.

Comment: This is answered at security.stackexchange.com/questions/240445/what-is-the-behaviour-of-csp-if-default-src-not-specified